# IIS7 mp4 files and html 5 video tag

Tags: video, iis-7

We have IIS7 on the server and there is a mp4 file, if we browse directly to it in firefox or IE it plays ok, but using html 5 video tag it says "No video with supported format and MIME type found".

I have added a MIME type for mp4 files of "video/mpeg" but this made no difference.

On my local computer which is using IIS7.5 it all works ok and there is no mime type at all for mp4 on that.

Comment: What is the content of the `<video>` tag?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry @JohnnyTisdale I can't remember, it was over 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in the Content Security Policy (CSP). I had to add the following to web.config:

```
media-src https://example.com;
```